# How to create a mock spring bean for a class having autowired dependencies

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, junit, mocking

Suppose I have a class called MainClass.

```
public class MainClass {
    @Autowired
    AutoWiredClass autoWiredClass;
}
```

I am trying to create a mock bean of MainClass using Mockito.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration
public class AutowiringTest {
    @Configuration
    static class AutowiringTestConfiguration{

        @Bean
        public MainClass mainClass() {
            return Mockito.mock(MainClass.class);
        }
    }

    @Autowired
    MainClass mainClass;

    @Test
    public void testBeanCreation(){
        assertNotNull(mainClass);
    }
}
```

I am getting this error while running the test case.

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: autowiring.AutoWiredClass autowiring.MainClass.autoWiredClass; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [autowiring.AutoWiredClass] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

I know I can achieve this using @Mock and @InjectMocks. But that's  not the solution I want.

My requirement is to create a mock bean of MainClass without creating an actual bean of AutowiredClass. Please help me how to achieve this.

Comment: What do you need the whole Spring thing for, if all you want to create a mock of MainClass? A mock will not contain anything else anyway...

Comment: I just gave a sample example. I have a use case where the class I want to test has multiple @Autowired fields. I want some of them to come from spring and some to get mocked.

Comment: But in that case, the main class itself cannot be a mock, which seems to be the case here. You can put mocks into a not-mock, but the other way round doesn't happen that often and would be a little bit more difficult, probably requiring an Answer object that redirects some call to mocks and some to the real objects.

Comment: @FlorianSchaetz , true. In my use case MainClass is not a mock. some dependencies inside Mainclass need to be mocked. I gave this example to simplify the question. If this question is answered, my use case will also be achieved.

Comment: In this case, make your MainClass use constructor or setter injection, then @Autowired the objects you need to autowire into your testcase, create the mocks and construct an instance of your MainClass manually with all these objects.

Comment: In that case, I am doing modification my code so that I can test it. Isn't there an answer to what I asked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Florian has already commented, you should try to create tests that do not need Spring at all, and you will not have those problems.

But, if there is no workaround possible, you can use a bit of magic with the [AutoMockRegistryPostProcessor](https://github.com/rinoto/spring-auto-mock/blob/master/src/main/java/sbg/rinoto/spring/mock/AutoMockRegistryPostProcessor.java).

You just need to add the `AutoMockRegistryPostProcessor` to the `@ContextConfiguration`, and it will create mocks for your missing dependencies:

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { AutowiringTest.class, AutoMockRegistryPostProcessor.class })
public class AutowiringTest {
    // no complains anymore, a mockito mock will be created for AutoWiredClass
```

The `AutoMockRegistryPostProcessor` class is not in maven, you will need to copy it in your project.

The docu is [here](https://github.com/rinoto/spring-auto-mock).

Comment: This did not work.
MainClass bean was not handled by the post processor.

`String [] beanNames = registry.getBeanDefinitionNames();
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(beanNames));`

The results did not have mainClass as one of the beans.

Comment: This was the result of the print statement.
`[org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor, org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor, org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor, org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor, autowiringTest, autoMockRegistryPostProcessor, org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importAwareProcessor, org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.enhancedConfigurationProcessor]
`

Comment: It worked. I forgot to add AutowiringTest.class in @ContextConfiguration.
But may I know why that's required? Mainclass bean was already being created without that change too.

Comment: An empty `@ContextConfiguration` tries to find the config classes by itself, and it finds your `AutowiringTestConfiguration`. As long as you specify one class in the `@ContextConfiguration` (and you need to do it to add `AutoMockRegistryPostProcessor`), you are overriding the automatic discovery, and need to explicitly add the config classes yourself.

Comment: @Ruben your `AutoMockRegistryPostProcessor` does not resolve `Qualifier` dependencies. Needs a little fix. You saved my life though, so thnx a lot.